# How to add a status minipage in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a web front-end and I want to have the same status minipage running on each page of my website. This is what I have so far

```
export default class Status extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           // some features
        };
    }

    recheck = event => {
        // some status check
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => this.check(), 1000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Status">
                {/*... some status */}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and I'd hope to have such component always rendered. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Sure, but is this the entirety of the React app you want to build? Or is there more to it? If this is it, then just import React and ReactDOM at the top of your file and connect it to the DOM with `ReactDOM.render`. If this is a subcomponent to the rest of your React app, then import it there and render. If you're always calling it, then it will always be rendered. Simple as that. You're leaving out the rest of your architecture, so I don't know the context, and I really don't know exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you render it in your root component, e.g. `App.js`, you should get the desired result.

Comment: @mccambridge this is just one component. I have an App.js that serves as the start point. However, I am not sure how I could also render this from App.js as a separated file.

Comment: @wdm Thanks for the comment. Please see my response above.

Comment: @Mr.cysl do you have a build process in place? Are you using webpack or something? Or are you loading react into a script tag in your HTML? Need more context. :)

Comment: @Mr.cysl import the component to App.js such as `import Status from './Status'` and in your `render` method include `<Status/>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some sample code on how to include your `Status` component within `App.js`

Edit: Per your comment I've included some examples of passing props to `<Status/>`

```
// App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Status from './Status'; // Status.js

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const bar = "World";
        return {
            <div className="App">
                ...some layout

                <Status foo="Hello" bar={bar}/>
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, if so, how should I pass my childProps (defined in App.js, originally passed through Routes) to the component?

Comment: @Mr.cysl I added some attributes to `<Status/>` to show how to pass down properties. More info here: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html